# What does `+''`` mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have this line of code in a project I am looking at - 
`cta = send(state + '_cta') || +''`

What does the `+''` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+''` is the unary `+` operator applied to the string literal `''` and the [unary `+` on strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B-40):

> **+str → str (mutable)**
>   If the string is frozen, then return duplicated mutable string.
>
> If the string is not frozen, then return the string itself.

It is common to put `# frozen_string_literal: true` in your Ruby files so that all string literals (such as `''`) are frozen (i.e. immutable). So `''` is often an immutable string but `+''` is a mutable version of `''`.

That means that this:

```
cta = send(state + '_cta') || +''
```

should leave a mutable string in `cta`.

---

As an aside, if `send(state + '_cta')` should give you a `String` or `nil` then you could also say:

```
cta = send(state + '_cta').to_s
```

since [`NilClass#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) gives you an unfrozen `''`. If `send(state + '_cta')` can return `false` then the `+''` and `to_s` versions are different of course.